# Some of the tables in just installed AdventureWorks 2008 are empty.What's up?

Tags: sql-server

Guys,i istalled this database, but all tables in Sales schema are empty (Sales.SalesOrderHeader for example). How this can be ?

Answer (score 0):

The insert batch(es) from the data population script were rolled back?  Or maybe they were bypassed?